# How to verify whether string value is in correct range in Data Frame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have DataFrame in Python pandas like below ("col1" is data type string):

```
col1
-------
14212614414
05261265140
82044114467
...
```

- Fifth and sixth values mean day of born.

How to check whether day are from the correct range, so fifth and sixth values should be from range 1 to 31.

```
col1        | col2
------------|-------
14212614414 | True
05261265140 | True
82044114467 | False
...
```

How can Ido that in Python Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the series.str accessor and slice the string, then treat it as an int with [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and check if it's [between](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) the numbers

```
df['col2']=df['col1'].str[4:6].astype(int).between(1,31)


col1    col2
0   14212614414 True
1   5261265140  True
2   82044114467 False
```

Comment: alternative is to skip type conversion and use `df['col1'].str[4:6].between('01', '31')`